# iPhone resolution sorting - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, resolution, assets

I have read on a lot of sites that for iPhone 6 Plus the image asset needs to be three times as big as the actual image, so it therefor needs to be a @3x image. And then @2x is for iPhone 6 all the way down to iPhone 4 and then just the original size for iPhone 3GS and below.

My main question is that am I right in saying this and if so, what if Apple changes the iPhone's screen size again one day, will they make developer make a @4x image too??? I just think its getting a bit out of hand.

What is the best way to sort all this image sizes out? Do you just make all the image assets for your app 3 times as big when you are designing them and then make a smaller @2x and @1x version of them??

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a catalogs they were introduced within Xcode5 I don't think it will go out of hand as if you do it properly you don't really have to do anything else than drag and drop your images and define just the name of the image when using the class method

> [UIImage imageNamed:];

You don't need to define the size iOS will choose the adequate size from your catalog. you don't even have to define the file type ("jpg, png, etc...")

Take a look to Apple documentation for catalogs I think that's the most organized way to keep your assets.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html

3gs phone just support till iOS6 the users with iOS6.x is not that high I personally do not support iOS 6 anymore in my apps for iPhone you can check the iOS adoption stats in the following link:

https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/ios_8/from_date:-29,report_unit:day,to_date:0